# How to change remote repository with git

Tags: git, repository, git-clone

I recently downloaded a git repository from which looks promising as a base for a project I'm starting for a client.

Before making too many changes, I'd like to upload it to a separate repository. From googling, it looks like it may be as simple as this:

`git remote set-url origin NEWURL`

where NEWURL is the new repository address.

My question: is NEWURL the address that ends in ".git"?

e.g.

```
 https://myname@bitbucket.org/myname/my-new-app.git
```

Also, is it automatically uploaded after that? Or do I have to do any additional commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the process to set the remote URL is correct. Additional steps needed:

1. Create a repository named `my-new-app` in BitBucket, under your account `myname`.
2. Use `git push -u origin master` to push the code to the BitBucket repository.